# Spring Boot initializes more DaoAuthenticationProviders than expected

Tags: java, authentication, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm fighting a "bug" similar to one Apple had recently in OS X :) An application authenticates users treating their password field not only as a bcrypt hash but also as a plaintext, so it allows special utility accounts to log in with an empty password.

There are a bunch of user records in the database and almost all of them has their password hashed with bcrypt. There are however a few special utility accounts with password hash field deliberately left empty (to make `BcryptPasswordEncoder#matches` always reject login attempts for them).

Placing breakpoints all over `ProviderManager` I can see multiple authentication providers initialized by spring:

- a "proper" `DaoAuthenticationProvider` with bcrypt encoder
- `AnonymousAuthenticationProvider`, which nobody configured, but at least I can guess it came from `permitAll()` or something alike.
- an unwanted `DaoAuthenticationProvider` with `PlaintextPasswordEncoder` which spoils all fun

We have another project where we don't use Spring Boot and with almost identical configuration it works as expected (passwords are never treated as plaintext, only as bcrypt hash). So my guess is: this "problem" has something to do with Spring Boot "configuration by convention" and I can't find how to override its behavior.

In this project I use the following configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    @Autowired
    AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/js/**", "/css/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login").permitAll()
                .loginProcessingUrl("/j_spring_security_check").permitAll()
                .successHandler(new SuccessHandler())
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")).permitAll()
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login");


        http.csrf().disable();
        http.headers().frameOptions().sameOrigin();
    }

    @Autowired
    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider);
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        final DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authenticationProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(15);
    }

}
```

Edit: If I get it correct, there's a way to configure global and local `AuthenticationManagerBuilder`s:

```
// Inject and configure global:
/*
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
}
*/

// Override method and configure the local one:
@Override
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
}
```

Doing that, I have now two instances of builder: one - local - has only the correct manager: bcrypt, the other one - global - has other 2 providers: anonymous and plaintext. Authentication behavior persists, application still uses **both** and lets users login with plaintext passwords. Uncommenting `configureGlobal` doesn't help too, in that case, global manager contains all three providers.

Comment: It is the not working one. I'll try that in a minute...

Comment: Nope, no luck. For some reason there are still all 3 authentication providers. `this.authenticationProviders.add(authenticationProvider);` is getting called multiple times and it is still possible to login with a plaintext password.

Comment: I'm confused now. I've put a breakpoint inside  `AuthenticationManagerBuilder#authenticationProvider` method and I clearly see two `AuthenticationManagerBuilder`s being configured during an application start: they are, for example AuthenticationManagerBuilder@7702 and WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter@7745. First one gets the correct provider alone. The latter one gets all 3 authentication providers added. Also, I've removed `@Autowired` as you suggested.

Comment: Please don't add "[Solved]" to the title or add the answer in the question. If an existing answer solves the problem mark it as "accepted" by selecting the tick underneath the answer score. If your solution is significantly different to the existing answers post it as your own answer and accept that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The configuration is explicitly providing the userDetailsService in multiple places without providing the `PasswordEncoder`. The easiest solution is to expose the `UserDetaisService` and `PasswordEncoder` as a Bean and delete all explicit configuration. This works because if there is no explicit configuration, Spring Security will discover the Beans and create authentication from them.

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http // Don't forget to remove userDetailsService
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/js/**", "/css/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login").permitAll()
                .loginProcessingUrl("/j_spring_security_check").permitAll()
                .successHandler(new SuccessHandler())
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")).permitAll()
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login");


        http.csrf().disable();
        http.headers().frameOptions().sameOrigin();
    }
    // UserDetailsService appears to be a Bean somewhere else, but make sure you have one defined as a Bean
    @Bean
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(15);
    }

}
```

The reason it is failing is because there is explicit configuration to use the UserDetailsService twice:

```java
@Autowired
@Override
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    // below Configures UserDetailsService with no PasswordEncoder
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService); 
    // configures the same UserDetailsService (it was used to create the authenticationProvider) with a PasswordEncoder (it was provided to the authenticationProvider)
    auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider);
}
```

If you want explicit configuration, you could use the following

```java
@Override
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
        .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder()); 
}
```

and delete the `authenticationProvider` bean along with the `@Autowired AuthenticationProvider`. Alternatively, you could just use the `AuthenticationProvider`, but not both.

Generally, the explicit configuration of AuthenticationManagerBuilder is only needed when you have multiple `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` with different authentication mechanisms. If you do not have the need for this, I recommend just exposing the `UserDetailsService` and (optionally) the `PasswordEncoder` as a Bean.

Note that if you expose a `AuthenticationProvider` as a Bean it is used over a `UserDetailsService`. Similarly, if you expose an `AuthenticationManager` as a Bean it is used over `AuthenticationProvider`. Finally, if you explicitly provide `AuthenticationManagerBuilder` configuration, it is used over any Bean definitions.

Comment: I tried what you suggest with no luck (it is most likely I misunderstood something due to my lack of spring knowledge). However, I solved a problem an hour later. It turned out that `protected void configure(HttpSecurity http)` was triggering the second `AuthenticationManagerBuilder` creation. So I provided my `AuthenticationProvider` bean and added `http.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)` to httpsecurity configuration. Everything seems to work as expected now. It might not be the correct solution though.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that `protected void configure(HttpSecurity http)` was triggering the second `AuthenticationManagerBuilder` creation. So I provided my `AuthenticationProvider` bean and added it to httpsecurity configuration. Everything seems to work as expected now. It might not be the correct solution though.
New configuration (works for me):

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    @Autowired
    AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;
    @Autowired
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider) // <== Important
                //.anonymous().disable() // <== This part is OK. If enabled, adds an anonymousprovider; if disabled, it is impossible to login due to "unauthenticated<->authenticate" endless loop.
                .httpBasic().disable()
                .rememberMe().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/js/**", "/css/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login").permitAll()
                .loginProcessingUrl("/j_spring_security_check").permitAll()
                .successHandler(new SuccessHandler())
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")).permitAll()
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login");    
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        final DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authenticationProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(15);
    }
}
```